# D3.js Dynamic Donut Chart with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

Currently trying to use mbostock's [dynamic d3 donut chart tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) and failing miserably.  The tutorial uses one csv file with two key/value pairs and sets them to radio buttons of the same name.  What if I'm pulling data in dynamically with one json array?  How do I still set two different radio buttons to toggle between data depending on what the year is?

The code below pulls in two different years in my code: 2000 and 2014.

```
var json = [ 
            { "education" : "GED", "amount" : 30, "year" : "2000" },
            { "education" : "GED", "amount" : 20, "year" : "2014" },
            { "education" : "Associate", "amount" : 20, "year" : "2000" },
            { "education" : "Associate", "amount" : 40, "year" : "2014" },
            ...
           ];
```

Comment: did you try to convert your json in CSV ?

Comment: It's being pulled in dynamically from a database and specifically put into this format.  The csv would be out of date as soon as it was made.

Comment: check out this http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/1/

Comment: The problem is the radio buttons switching between the two different years.  I can make a static donut chart from json I'm just having trouble making it transition with the years.

Comment: okey check event and rendering of chart